# How to modify single bit in a byte array element?

Tags: java

I have array of bytes each holding one byte which is 8 bits. Lets say I want to modify 5th bit of first element of the array without changing anything else. Is there any simple way to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to set it, do

```
bytes[0] |= (byte) (1 << 5);
```

...which OR's the first element in the byte array with the binary representation of 1, shifted to the left 5 places...which is the same thing as setting the 5th bit.

If you want to clear the 5th bit, do

```
bytes[0] &= (byte) ~(1 << 5);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have `byte[] a`, you can modify the 5th bit of the first element using bit operations like this:
set to 1: `a[0] |= 1<<5`
set to 0: `a[0] &= ~(1<<5)`
If you want a nicer API that wraps the bit operations, check out the BitSet class.